# How to loop through Node.js array

Tags: node.js

How can I display the variables of the array?

Code:

```
   console.log(rooms);
   for (var i in rooms) {
      console.log(i);
   }
```

Output:

```
{ rooms: 
       [ { room: 'Raum 1', persons: 1 },
         { room: 'R2', persons: 2 },
         { room: 'R3', persons: 3 } ] }
rooms
```

Comment: looks like rooms is not an array, its object, use rooms.rooms in your loop

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[For..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is used to loop through the properties of an object, it looks like you want to loop through an array, which you should use either [For Of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
for(const val of rooms) {
    console.log(val)
}
```

Comment: you should use `const` instead of `let`, i know, it seems odd, but in each iteration the `val` is constant and limited to the scope between brackets `{}`. You just need to use `let` if you reassign the variable `val` inside the block.

Answer (score 15):

Using [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with your code example (room is an object) would look this:

```
temp1.rooms.forEach(function(element) 
{ 
    console.log(element) 
});
```

Using [For of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) with your code sample (if we wanted to return the rooms) looks like:

```
for(let val of rooms.room)
{ 
    console.log(val.room); 
}
```

Note: notable difference between For of and forEach, is For of supports breaking and forEach has no way to break for stop looping (without throwing an error).

Answer (score 8):

```
for (const i in rooms) {
  console.log(rooms[i]);
}
```

Note it's good practice to do a `hasOwnProperty` check with `in` and it is for objects. So you're better off with `for...of` or `forEach`.